# Using VBOs, is glVertexPointer/glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY) required?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Can I use glVertexAttribPointer/glEnableVertexAttribArray even for the vertex position, and use my own attribute for the vertex position instead of gl_Vertex?

Comment: Take a look at `glVertexAttribPointer`

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL doesn't know what a vertex position is, unless you're actually using `gl_Vertex`. Generic attributes ([user-defined vertex shader inputs](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Inputs)) are just data; what matters is what your shader does with the data.

How you generate the vertex shader output `gl_Position` is entirely up to you; OpenGL doesn't care one way or another. You don't have to pass a "position" at all; you could generate it via some algorithm.

Comment: Right, my question was is there anything special about gl_Vertex? I had presumed that there isn't, as long as gl_Position gets computed correctly, and just wanted a confirmation. Thanks!